# Does Emacs ECB can refresh the directory automatic?

Tags: emacs

When I open emacs in my workspace, and I rename one directory in shell, Does ECB can refresh the directory tree automatic ? If not, which shortcut key will help ? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is no - it's not possible to make ECB scan directories for arbitrary external changes via customization. It would require some coding to implement this feature.

Comment: right , I need to close the parent tree node, and open it again, then i can see the change